# Crystal Reports Legends

Tags: crystal-reports, legend, bar-chart

Is there a way to force a Bar Chart legend in Crystal Report 11.5 to display its objects in a particular order?

For Example, say I am reporting on the consumption of "Bananas" and "Apples" by State.  The Bar Chart should display the percentage of people who eat these fruits by county (Percent Bar Chart).  The "Apples" percentage always displays on top of the bar chart and the "Bananas" on the bottom.  The legend for this graph also displays the "Apple" color first, then the "Banana" color.  However, if the "Banana" percentage is 0% the legend displays the "Banana" color first on the legend.  This creates a inconsistent report (with plenty of complaints).

I would like the "Banana" color to always display second in the legend.  Hope I didn't confuse anyone and any ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:
1. Right-click to go into the **Chart Expert**. Go into the **Data** tab.
2. If it isn't already set to it, set the grouping method thingy on the top right to **On Change of**
3. Click **Order**, then **Specified Order**
4. There are 2 new tabs: **Specified Order** and **Others**.  Use the first to decide which groups go first and the second to decide what to do with the rest.

Since you're specifying the order of your groups in the chart, Crystal won't try to auto-decide which ones go first. Step 2 may be an issue for your chart depending on how you set it up. In that case, I suggest making a new chart from scratch.

I can't call myself an expert. I hope this helps.

Comment: This solved the issue of getting rid of the "Sum of..." added to the fields in the legend. A lot of people have this problem with Crystal. This did it for me!

Comment: @TiltingCode, I'm glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I was able to replicate your issue. It is a little strange, but I was able to bypass the issue by changing the chart to one of the other 2 bar chart types ("Stacked Bar Chart" or a "Side-By-Side Bar Chart"). I'd recommend using one of those, or perhaps even a pie chart.

Comment: I changed it to all sorts of chart types and the same issue occurs for me.  Also, on the Crystal Report forums, any questions related to the legend are not answered (go figure).